# Protege OWL Calculate the sum of a property of the children of a class

Tags: sum, rdf, owl, protege, reasoning

in my ontology i got a Recipe-Class which got multiple "children", which are of the class Food. Those foods have Nutritions (protein, carbs, fats...).

Recipe->Food->Nutrition->NutritionAmount

Is it possible to calculate the sum of the proteins of Recipe x with reasoning rules? With Sparql its working well.

Comment: The only way I can suggest is https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRLCore#Aggregation

Comment: OWL reasoning is monotonic. Aggregation is not. A workaround in OWL could be https://sourceforge.net/p/meloproject/code/ci/master/tree/OWL/examples/list_sum.owl